# Is original_filename method in ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is `original_filename` method in `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` safe to use to save as file in host system, without further sanitize it?

Comment: It's just converted to utf, but AFAIK most uploader implementations use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, it doesn't look like they do any checking of the filename, so unless they do it somewhere else (which would be bad design and thus unlike the Rails team), the real question is: what harm can a filename do? The only cases I can think of that it might be possible to use it maliciously is:

1. if the file is named ".". Those can be hard to delete if you actually succeed in creating them. I doubt that Ruby would let you save a file by that name, you can try it and see. If it doesn't, this this point can be ignored.
2. or maybe a really long name might cause a buffer overflow somewhere deeper in the API code of the OS.

Note that neither of those *should* be a problem. OSes try to make it impossible to create . files, but I've seen it done. And since (most?) filesystems already have a max filename limit, they should just error or truncate the file for you; truncating yourself is a borderline paranoid measure to protect against buffer overflow exploits that may be found in the OS's API code in the future. Such an exploit is very unlikely to exist.

So, if you really want to, just check for these two cases and you should be okay. You might want to do this by subclassing the UploadedFile class and adding the functionality that, if the name is "." or "..", then you just give it a random name; and if it is over, say 100 chars, then truncate it.

But I would say that neither of these are likely enough to warrant the introduction of a nonstandard class into your code base. I would just try saving the file by the given name and depend on the underlying file saving API to catch errors, check for said errors, and report them back to the user.